# How do i check if the node is expanded in Kendo treeView

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a Kendo treeView. I want to collapse the node on single click (the default is on double click). To do that I need to know if the node is expanded already so I can call collapse(e.node). So, how do I check if the node has been expanded already?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test with `$(e.node).attr("data-expanded") === "true"` or `kendoTreeView._expanded(e.node)`, however if your goal is to collapse/expand depending on the current state, you can simply call

`kendoTreeView.toggle(e.node);`