# Remember nodes expanded between page navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

In my Asp.NET MVC 4 application, Page 1 has a Kendo treeview. On Page 1, user can click on a node X and expand its descendant nodes as deep as he wants.  Then he clicks on node X and from there he goes to Page 2; he does some work for node X.  Next, from Page 2, the user can go back to Page 1.  I'd like once the user is back to Page 1, Page 1 should be able to show the same expanding & collapse status for node X and other nodes as originally. Please advise.  Thank you.

Details:

Page 1, user clicks on Node X and expand its descendant nodes like:

- Tree root

  - Node A
  - Node B
  - Node X

    - Node X.1

      - Node X.1.1
      - Node X.1.2
    - Node X.2
    - Node X.3

      - Node X.3.1
  - Node Y
  - Node Z

    - Node Z.1
    - Node Z.2

Then the user clicks on Node X and goes to Page 2 and does some work. Then, he click on a button or link to be back to Page 1.  Once he is on Page 1 again, I would like the treeview widget should be able to show nodes as mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there are a bunch of problems to solve:

**1: How to maintain state between page reloads**

Some of your options: [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie), [session / local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage), saving it to the server (e.g. by sending an ajax request to the server)

**2: How to know which nodes in a treeview are expanded**

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006877/how-do-i-check-if-the-node-is-expanded-in-kendo-treeview) should work:

```
var expandedNodes = $("#treeview").find(".k-item").filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr("data-expanded") === "true";
});
```

**3: How to serialize the list of expanded nodes so it can be restored**

This really depends on how you create your treeview: do you have a data source so that each node has a unique id? do you create the treeview from an html structure (`<ul></ul>`)? does each node have a unique text or can there be duplicates?

Assuming each node has a unique text, you could simply serialize the text of each expanded node, e.g. in this form (with the pipe char as a delimiter):

```
// note that you'd need to do this sorted by the node's nesting level, 
// i.e. first level nodes need to come first, then second level etc,
// so you can expand in the same order
var serialized = "text1|text2|text3"; // store this using cookies or w/e
```

A simple implementation (which may not be enough for your case):

```
$(expandedNodes).each(function () {
    serialized += tree.text(this) + "|";
});
```

and then ..

**4: How to deserialize the expanded nodes and expand the treeview accordingly**

You could do this to restore it:

```
// load serialized from wherever you stored it, then ..
var deserialized = serialized.split("|");
$(deserialized).each(function () {
    var node = tree.findByText(this);

    tree.expand(node);
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/rwfsf/)

Comment: Nice code but is this code used for the kendo treeview.?